# Apply same Lifecycle rule to multiple buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a lifecycle rule for 1 s3 bucket. Is there any method by which I can apply that rule to all the buckets/multiple S3 buckets or do I have to manually add same rule one by one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option where you can apply the same lifecycle rule to multiple buckets. You have to manually update for each bucket

Answer (score 1):

**No, you cannot.** Lifecycle rules are applied per bucket, they cannot (yet?) be created independently of them. The flexibility they offer in terms of targeting objects is purely with a bucket where they can be applied to either all objects within this bucket or only a subset (filter on prefix).

if you want automate why not use Infrastructure as a code tool like terraform or cloud formation

Comment: Thank you Jatin for the answer.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same using Terraform, but there also I have to create separate resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" for each bucket.

Any other way to achieve this by creating just one resource and applying it to all the required buckets?

Comment: @SagarAjmire You can upvote it, if it helped you :)

You can use a for each block for multiple s3 buckets. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65243393/13126651